# Problemas con equipo en red

Tags: redes

Hey chicos tengo este problema:

Tengo una pequeña red de trabajo con 1 equipo actuando de servidor, y 5 que se conectan a el para envio/recibo de archivos, pero hoy un equipo no me deja entrar al servidor(pc), me pide administrar credenciales, usuario y contraseña, se las ingreso pero no accesa al servidor. Reitero que un dia simplememte ya no quiso conectar:

**1**- El equipo servidor tiene desactivo contraseña para entrar.
**2**- Desactivé el antivirus y el firewall y sigue sin funcionar.
**3**- Borré la red y le dí de alta nuevamente.
**4**- Establecí IP manualmente para conexión
y ninguna de estas soluciones ha funcionado

Comment: Empieza probando si hay conectividad entre los equipos. Lanza un comando ping desde el equipo a la ip del servidor. Si no tienes conexión, seguiría mirando tema de cables (o wifi, tampoco diste muchos detalles de tu red), drivers, tarjeta de red, etc. Si hay conectividad por ping y no entras a la carpeta compartida, entonces obviamente es mala configuración de la compartición de archivos (me estoy imaginando que es una carpeta compartida de windows... no se). Es que no das casi datos y para que te pudieramo ayudar tendrías que poner todos los datos posibles de tu red.

Comment: ok gracias por tu ayuda si perdon se me paso datos......la conexion es via cable y tmb mande el ping al servidor y si hay respuesta, ya verifique en dispositivos y el driver de red no necesita actualizacion.....lo que se me hace raro fue que de 1 dia para otro hiciera eso(o el usuario no me dice si le movio algo)

Answer (score 0):

Si es una red de Windows, y el servidor actúa como servidor de dominio, entonces revisa que la fecha y hora de la PC no sea errónea. El servidor puede rechazar las credenciales de un cliente si este presenta una fiche y hora incorrectas.

Aunque el servidor tenga los permisos de acceso relajados y sin contraseña, las computadoras dentro de un dominio tienen una «cuenta del equipo» que se crea al unirse al dominio, y si esa cuenta es rechazada por el servidor por una discrepancia de fecha y hora, no tendras acceso ningún servicio del servidor.